# EntityFrameworkCore FromSqlRaw not mapping correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure called `GetZonesAssignedToCustomer` and I am using entity framework core, **which is duplicating mappings.** I have checked the stored procedure and all of the data is correct when I run it in SSMS.

I have a class that looks like:

```
public class ZoneSprocResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ZoneType { get; set; }
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    public string StreamId { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling the stored procedure like:

```
var a = await _context.Set<ZoneSprocResult>().FromSqlRaw(command).ToListAsync();
```

This is what it looks like in `OnModelCreating`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    /// other entities here

   builder.Entity<ZoneSprocResult>()'

   /// other entities here
}
```

However, it is returning the correct amount of records the issue is that StreamId is repeated. So it's almost like it's using `FirstOrDefault` on these records.

Now, I was checking my sanity and ran this code in the same method:

```
        var table = new DataTable();
        using var connection = new SqlConnection("My ConnectionString");
        using var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
        using var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);

        var checkList = new List<ZoneSprocResult>();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var result = new ZoneSprocResult()
            {
                Id = row[0].ToString(),
                ParentId = row[1]?.ToString()??String.Empty,
                Name = row[2]?.ToString() ?? String.Empty,
                ZoneType = int.Parse(row[3].ToString()),
                AddressId = row[4].ToString(),
                IsEnabled = bool.Parse(row[5]?.ToString()??"0"),
                Tags = row[6].ToString(),
                StreamId = row[7].ToString(),
            };
            checkList.Add(result);
        }
```

Which it's correct when I change `return a;` to `return checkList;`

So on to my question, Is there a way to map the way FromSqlRaw maps the results, if so how?

Comment: Why are you even mapping rows to properties? I feel like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: And how your data result looks like? I guess you have either name or type mismatch and that is causing mapping problem...

Comment: Have you tryed to use : var a = await _context.Set().FromSqlRaw(command).ToListAsync(); without strongly typing it ? So you'll see what FromSqlRaw returns to you without the conversion to ZoneSprocResult. At least this should help you to see what is going wrong...

Comment: I have updated the question, I realized I left that out

Comment: @David I think there is no non generic `.Set()` version in *EF Core*, which is what he is using, if he tagged correctly

Comment: Yeah... I think you're right. But there is for sure a type mismatch as pointed by @onedevteam.com . I've used FromSqlRaw quite a few times and it works perfectly...

Comment: there absolutely is a [generic version of Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Set__1). in EFCore, and I figured the issue out. I had to add `.AsNoTracking()`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to you EF context:

```
public virtual DbSet<ZoneSprocResult> ZoneSprocResults { get; set; }
```

And replace your model builder with this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<ZoneSprocResult>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```